# Error loading entities with a navigation property using custom metadata

Tags: breeze

I have the following implementation of a custom metadata scenario using the boiler plate with breeze.metadata-helper 1.0.7 and BreezeJS 1.4.16:

```
    function addFoo() {
        addType({
            shortName: 'Foo',
            dataProperties: {
                Id: { type: ID },
                BarId: { type: ID }
            },
            navigationProperties: {
                Bar: {
                    entityTypeName: 'Bar',
                    associationName: 'Foo_Bar',
                    foreignKeyNames: ['BarId']
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function addBar() {
        addType({
            shortName: 'Bar',
            dataProperties: {
                Id: { type: ID },
            }
        });
    }
```

Upon completion of query (provided below) execution i receive the following error: **TypeError: newValue.getProperty is not a function**.

```
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Foos').expand('Bar');
    manager.execute(query).catch(function(error) { });
```

HTTP response contains the following JSON:

```
    [{"Id":1,"BarId":2,"Bar":{"Id":2}}]
```

Though this query works fine if i replace *foreignKeyNames: ['BarId']* with *invForeignKeyNames: ['Id']*. And still, in the latter case the navigation property *Bar()* of *foo* entity is not of entity type *Bar* but a simple javascript object.

The questions are:

1) Why the query with *foreignKeyNames* fails

2) Why foo.Bar() is not an entity of type Bar

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with how you are serializing the result of your query.  Take a look at the JsonResultsAdapter documentation where it discusses how to handle references in the json payload.  You may need a custom JsonResultsAdapter ( pretty easy to write once you understand the idea).